# Get 5 day Weather Forecast with JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, api

I am having trouble getting the JSON table to pull up for the 5 day forecast.

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="city-search">Search For A City: 
        <input type="text" id="cityInput" style="text-transform: uppercase" />
        <button class="searchBtn" type="submit"><span class="oi oi-magnifying-glass"></span></button>
    </div>
```

Here is my JQuery

```
var apiFore = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=' + cityName + '&appid='+{appid};
$.getJSON(apiFore, weatherForecast);
function weatherForecast(foreData) {
    console.log("5-day: " + foreData.list.main.temp);
};
```

This is what I get in the console, no matter what JSON item I try to pull.
[image]

Comment: Do you mean `var apiFore = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=' + cityName + '&appid={appid}';` ?

Comment: As already pointed out, the parameters you are passing to your URL look wrong.  What the error is telling you is that you can't get the `temp` from `foreData.list.main.temp`, because `foreData.list.main` is not defined - likely because of the problem already described.  If you want to see what you *do* get back, try `console.dir(foreData)`.  Lastly, [why you should not post images of code/error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).